# Javascript global variable is undefined,why?

Tags: javascript

hello please take a look at my code below

```js
var vsize; //global variable
function veg7() {
  vsize = 7;
}

function veg10() {
  vsize = 10;
}

function getCBP() {
  if (vsize == 7) {
    alert(vsize);
  } else {
    alert(vsize);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getCBP()" value="getCBP()">

<div class="main-menu">
  <ul style="padding-left:13px; position:relative;top:41px;margin-bottom:0px;">

    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="veg7()">7" Veg</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="veg10()">10" Veg</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="nonveg7()">7" Non Veg</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="nonveg10()">10" Non Veg</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="pizaxx()">Pizaxx</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="sideOrder()">Side Orders</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

if any event access the function veg7() or function veg10() (it is dynamic) and changes the value of vsize accordingly then why am i getting vsize as undefined.

please help me..i need the value of vsize in getCBP().

Comment: pls, give all code, with part where you call this functions

Comment: I don't see where you call veg7 or verg10?

Comment: Provide a fiddle with your problem.

Comment: I edited your code to make the snippet live and make the getCBP function callable … and I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: no it is still problematic i dont know why?

Comment: @Dinesh — What does "it is still problematic" mean? The live demo in your question **works**.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* undefined, but **declared**.
You are executing your function before assigning a value to your variable `vsize`.

you should declare `var vsize = 0` (or any value), or run one of your `veg` functions before running `getCBP`.

Comment: getCBP() is the checkbox's onchange event function. so when user select any <li> from above and then checks the checkbox the it should alert() the vsize value

Answer (score 1):

Try `var vsize = -1;`

If you now see `-1` instead of `undefined`, that means your functions are never called.

Note: I'm using `-1` because that's easier to spot as an "error" than 0.